# How to get errors details from android.database.SQLException?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database in my android app with two separate columns that have a UNIQUE constraint. When entering data and an SQLException exception is thrown I want to know which field's unique constraint was violated so I can take appropriate action.

Comment: can you show the insert code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `java.lang.SQLException` on which `android.database.SQLException` is based has methods `int getErrorCode()` and `String getSQLState()` which should be able to help you get details.

Answer (score 0):

Database constraints are mostly intended to catch programming errors.

If detecting duplicates is part of your app's logic, you should manually check for them.